# How to use VTK_array in VTK pipeline (Python)?

Tags: python, vtk, pydicom

I am new to `vtk` and am trying to do volume rendering with a DICOM file.

When I try to read the DICOM file using VTK with the following code:

```
import vtk
reader = vtk.vtkDICOMImageReader()
reader.SetDirectoryName(r"C:\Users\I_0001")
reader.Update()
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: In ..\IO\Image\vtkDICOMImageReader.cxx, line 143
vtkDICOMImageReader (000001DC61D2FED0): Couldn't open C:\Users\I_0001

ERROR: In ..\IO\Image\vtkDICOMImageReader.cxx, line 237
vtkDICOMImageReader (000001DC61D2FED0): Either a filename was not specified or the specified directory does not contain any DICOM images.

ERROR: In ..\Common\ExecutionModel\vtkExecutive.cxx, line 753
vtkCompositeDataPipeline (000001DC5C4A0A90): Algorithm vtkDICOMImageReader(000001DC61D2FED0) returned failure for request: vtkInformation (000001DC5F8E72A0)
  Debug: Off
  Modified Time: 207
  Reference Count: 1
  Registered Events: (none)
  Request: REQUEST_DATA
  FORWARD_DIRECTION: 0
  ALGORITHM_AFTER_FORWARD: 1
  FROM_OUTPUT_PORT: 0
```

I know the file is not corrupted as it works when I try to read it with pydicom.  I tried to read the files with pydicom into a numpy array and then use the numpy_support.numpy_to_vtk to convert into a vtk array. But then I don’t know how to insert those images into my vtk pipeline that uses the reader.GetOutputPort() to initiate the pipeline. **Can someone help me to insert my DICOM file images which are VTK arrays into the VTK pipeline?**

This is my current code:

```
# reading the data and converting it to VTK array using numpy_support
fileVolume = r"C:\Users\I_0001"
dicomVolume = pydicom.read_file(fileVolume)
shape = dicomVolume.pixel_array.shape
VTK_data = numpy_support.numpy_to_vtk(num_array=dicomVolume.pixel_array.ravel(), deep=True, array_type=vtk.VTK_FLOAT)


#need to insert VTK data here instead of using the vtk DICOM Image Reader
# Create the reader for the data.
reader = vtk.vtkDICOMImageReader()
reader.SetDirectoryName(r"C:\Users\I_0001")
reader.Update()

mapper = vtk.vtkDataSetMapper()
mapper.SetInputData(reader.GetOutput())
```

Comment: Is I_0001 the actual DICOM file or a folder that contains DICOM files?

Comment: About how to create VTK objects and pipeline from numpy, you can look at this [example](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/Utilities/VTKWithNumpy/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the VTKWithNumpy [example](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/Utilities/VTKWithNumpy/) linked by @Nico Vuaille I was able to convert my numpy array into a VTK image object.